# Override abstract class in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

In Magento 1 I could copy abstract class to local or community directory and Magento used it, when autoload load this class.

Is there some solution to make to Magento loads my class instead  `vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php`?

Preferences in `di.xml` for abstract classes does not work. Plugins only?

Answer (score 12):

> Plugins only?

Yes. You can write plugins for abstract classes and plugins should always be preferred over preferences if possible.

Preferences are useful if you want to **replace** an implementation. I can't think of a use case to replace the implementation for all models that extend `AbstractModel`, if that's even logically possible. So what you probably want is to **add or change functionality** and this is what plugins are for.

Comment: Hi, how can i override a protected function from abstract class in this case ? could you please help

Comment: That's not possible. The best is to try to find a way to add plugins to the public methods that use the protected method, and change the behavior in this way, even if it involves more code and some duplication.

Comment: "I can't think of a use case to replace the implementation for all models that extend AbstractModel" I have such a use case: I have payment module, which uses abstract base class for 4 controllers, each using a method from base to verify the response from payment gateway. Now, the response has changed and I would have to change all 3.

Answer (score 8):

Full solution: include replaced classes before magento autoload them.
So step by step:

1. In file `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` add row

   ```
   $pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/etc/ClassReplacer.php';
   ```
2. In `app/etc` place file `ClassReplacer.php` with content

   ```
   class ClassReplacer
   {
       public function includeReplacedFiles($src)
       {
           try {
               $replacedFiles = $this->listDir($src, false, true);
               foreach ($replacedFiles as $replacedFile) {
                   include_once $src . $replacedFile;
               }
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               return;
           }
       }

       protected function listDir($dir, $prependDir = false, $recursive = false, $entityRegexp = null, $currPath = '')
       {
           if (!is_dir($dir)) {
               return array();
           }
           $currPath = $prependDir ? $dir : $currPath;
           $currPath = $currPath !== '' ? rtrim($currPath, '/') . '/' : '';
           $files = array();
           foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
               if (in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
                   continue;
               }
               $entity = $currPath . $file;
               if ($recursive && is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
                   $files = array_merge($files, $this->listDir("$dir/$file", false, true, $entityRegexp, $entity . '/'));
                   continue;
               }
               if ($entityRegexp && !preg_match($entityRegexp, $entity)) continue;
               $files[] = $entity;
           }
           return $files;
       }
   }
   $replace = new ClassReplacer();
   $replace->includeReplacedFiles(dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/Magento/');
   ```
3. Place to `app/code/Magento` some class, which will be replaced, e.g. `app/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php`

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157797/magento-2-product-category-indexing-issue-override

Comment: Dirty hack, but some times it might be helpful to be able to do that. M1 required manual changes in core classes (so copy to app/code/local) if you wanted invoice PDF to look different, I bet there will be some case where this will be needed.

Answer (score 8):

If abstract class have any public or protected method you want to override, there is a way actually if you can't use plugins.

I had to override method `_processDownload` inside `\Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Download`, addings some 'if-s' inside. (If anyone has idea how can I add something like this inside method using plugins I will be gratful). Class is abstract so preference didn't worked. Plugins too, as method is protected. The thing I had to do was override all class extending from `Download`, using preference. These classes:

`Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Download\Link`
`Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Download\LinkSample`
`Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Download\Sample`

And inside them rewrite method from parent class (the one I wass supposed to override). So actually code of overridden methods was copied to three places and was exactly the same.

It's not ideal but, works.

Comment: i'm facing same issue!

Answer (score 5):

You can try using Magento Plugin for enhancing existing functionality of any Abstract class, although the scope of the function should be Public.
Recently I worked on same issue where I need to exclude products having a custom attribute assigned from the **Recently viewed product list**.

I used plugin for the function named **getItemsCollection** from the class named **Magento\Reports\Block\Product\AbstractProduct** using the following syntax:

file: app\code\Package\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
    <plugin name="Package_Module::aroundGetItemsCollection" type="Package\Module\Block\Viewed" sortOrder="20"/>
</type>
```

file: app\code\Package\Module\Block\Viewed.php

```
public function afterGetItemsCollection(
    $subject, $result
) {
    $result = $result->addAttributeToFilter('skip_hire_product', [['neq' => 1], ['null' => true]], 'left');
    return $result;
}
```

You can use around as well as before plugins too.
Hope this work for you.

Comment: i got success with above code in one of my requirement, actually i wanted to change some functionality of email module abstract class method and Plugin helped me to achieve this, thanks