# How to override the model class in magento2

Tags: magento2

i am trying to override **\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod** class method **assignData** method in my custom class but its not working.

Model class

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
class PaymentCustomData extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory, \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory, \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger, \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null, \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null, array $data = array()) {
        die(__METHOD__);exit;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $extensionFactory, $customAttributeFactory, $paymentData, $scopeConfig, $logger, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
    public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data) {
        var_dump($data->getData());
        exit;

     return $this;
    }

}
```

di.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
        <preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod" type="Vendor\Module\Model\PaymentCustomData" />
    </config>
```

Comment: What do you need to modify in the `assignData` ? Depending on your needs, using plugins would be more appropriate

Comment: i want to save my custom filed data in payment table.

Comment: You can try with remove construct() from your file

Comment: already checked but my custom class file is not calling.

Comment: refer link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2

Comment: try removing the constructor