# Mangeto 2: How to override core abstract class function?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, magento-2.1.3, class

[Magento 2: How to Override Abstract Class for Product Category Indexing Issue?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157797/magento-2-product-category-indexing-issue-override)

I need to override below files one function only

**magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\AbstractAction.php**

```
protected function isRangingNeeded()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: extend this class in your custom module and change `isRangingNeeded` function in your cutsom class.

Comment: Please post code