# Category product count not showing properly in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, product-list

I have assigned more than 30k products to one category in my website, but when i visit that category on frontend it is shwoing only 10000 products on the category list page.

In admin panel the count is 32500 for that category. Why it is not showing accurate count? Is there any setting to for setting the limit.?

Please someone advise me.

Answer (score 2):

By Default magento2 show 10,000 Products in category. if you have more than 10k products in your category then you have to change the size in **search_request.xml** file :

Creating custom module to override the search_request.xml file. i have attached custom module 
[Download](https://github.com/hafizjee/Show-More-10k-Products-in-Frontend)

Comment: Excellent, save my day!!

Answer (score 0):

*`Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\AbstractAction`*

**RANGE_CATEGORY_STEP constant from 500 to 5000;**

now run the indexers. Now it should show the correct count.

Comment: Please update me full code, we need to override this file is it? can you update me code for plugin or something else

Comment: first check directly. is this working or not ?

Comment: I changed directly and reinndex also i done but its same again

Comment: okay this is not working code..sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento's core bug and it's already fixed in **magento2.2** version

if you are using below 2.2 version then follow this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8681#issuecomment-286422113)

Hope this will help you, to increase count into `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\AbstractAction` class is not the proper solution at all.

Here is also posted same [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158286/55928)

Comment: I am using 2.2.5

Comment: magento says they have solved this issue if you faced still this issue and please follow this steps https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8681#issuecomment-286422113

Comment: Followed the steps and overrided the file mentioned there, but no success

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**File:** **`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/AbstractAction.php`**

**Line number approx:** 379

Change this code:

```
protected function isRangingNeeded()
{
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
protected function isRangingNeeded()
{
    return false;
}
```

Then do the reindexing and check the frontend again.

Comment: yes tried it, but no effect after reindex also