# proper way to Override the php file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to override the file 
`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\match.php`
and make the

```
const MINIMAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 3;
```

to

```
const MINIMAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 1;
```

should I change it in vendor itself or override. help me with the override.

`Minimal Query Length` under `Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search` is set to be 1
[image]

Comment: Use 'Plugins' for that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the setting `Minimal Query Length` under `Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`
I think changing this setting will be the same and will fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Already the "Minimal Query Length" is set to be 1

Comment: @AnandhuVijayan What exactly os your requirement. Why do you want to change this value?

Comment: In my project most of the product have 2 letter items like (GX,IC etc..).So I need to start search with 2 character, now "no result" dialog is shown when count is 2. I need to start search at 2 character. I try to change the count in admin panel as above (Screen shot) . But thus didn't works. When I change the core value it works fine. That's why I need to override this file.