# I want to add one more method same like getUrl method in Vendor/Magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php.How we can override?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

I want to add one more method same like getUrl method in `Vendor/Magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php.`

How can we override in magento2.1.12?

If I directly add a new method in `Vendor/Magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php`, what is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Class override is not possible as AbstractTemplate is an abstract class. See more at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108058/4564

Also,  working on original file `Vendor/Magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php`  is not a good idea because of when you upgrade Magento version that time that class will be replaced by the updated version of that file.