# How to override abstactclass methods in magento2?

Tags: magento2, abstract-class

I want to override \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity's method _saveValidatedBunches.

I have tried using preference but it's not working.

Can anyone help me

Comment: I think using plugin is the way out for this.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to get this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2

here you go, seems similar requirement.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra have you found any solution for this?