# How can I override controller with module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to override this file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Shipment/AbstractShipment/View.php`

So I can change line 49 from `setModule('adminhtml')` to `setModule('adminhtml')`

Any help is very appreciated

I've tried creating `app/code/MyCompany/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Shipment/AbstractShipment/View.php` with this in the file:

```
namespace             
MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment;


class View extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\View {

public function execute()
{
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward $resultForward */
        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id')) {
            $resultForward->setController('order_shipment')
                ->setModule('adminhtml')
                ->setParams(['come_from' => 'shipment'])
                ->forward('view');
            return $resultForward;
        } else {
            return $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        }
    }
}
```

`module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

`di.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\View" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\View"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you extend class you have to pass value of parent counstruct
so please add below code in your file

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $resultForwardFactory);
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I need to change line 49 from setModule('adminhtml') to setModule('adminhtml') otherwise I get a 404 error when I try to view a shipment

Comment: what is the diff between setModule('adminhtml') and  setModule('adminhtml')?

Comment: ok got it you mean setModule('admin') to setModule('adminhtml').

ok so what's the error are you facing?
Have made above changes and clear your generated folder and cache?

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache and generated everything. I get a `"404 Not Found"` error when I try to view a shipment in admin panel under Sales. If I change `'admin'` to `'adminhtml'` then it works, but I can't get the override to work. The GitHub issue is here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16567

Comment: @VirtusO Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\View is abstarct class so it's not override by preference. you have to override using plugin or you have to override it's parent class

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks. Do you know how I can override it then?

Comment: if you want to use plugin below link will help you to override it:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2

or if you want to override parent class you can do it by preference