# Override Magento Ui dataprovider

Tags: ui

Anyone can suggest how to override below class

Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav.php file

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to override a public method I recommend that you use a plugin

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108058/70343

If you are trying to override a non-public method your only option may be something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110825/70343

Comment: Thanks Dominic. I will check your answer