# Override Abstract class in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, di

I'm using magento v2.4.3, i tried to override **\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress** like this:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence> 
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Magento/Customer/Model/Address/AbstractAddress.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Customer\Model\Address;

class AbstractAddress extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress
{
 /**
     * Retrieve region name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
      die('SUCCESS');
    }
}
```

The override file not firing at all it seems

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It could be that an Abstract class is technically not loaded by the object manager therefore the rewrite will be ignored. Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class cannot be overridden.

As per your post, you want to do some customization on `getRegion` method. As `getRegion` is a public function then you can use plugin for customization.